# My friends iPad 3 charges so slow! Give me some solutions plz!

Tags: ipad

Hello there my friends iPad is *charging so slow!* **would you please help me?**
Ok, first teh iPad charges with a third party 30 pin cable and usb power adapter. Teh iPad runs on **ios 8** and teh battery is never changed.

Comment: We need some more info: Are you using an Apple-branded charger? What about the USB cable? Was the battery ever replaced? If so, by whom? Was it dropped or water-damaged recently? What version of iOS is it running?

Comment: Ok red eagle the iPad _charges_ with a third party cable and usb charger it was only dropped on the bed 3 times only the iPad is running in iOS 8.3-8.4.1

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35270/iphone-4-will-charge-in-wall-but-wont-sync-or-charge-via-usb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is mostly the charger. Buy the official Apple one (the $20 one) and the iPad should charge *much* faster. Also, updating to iOS 9 couldn't hurt, either.