# My friends iPhone 4s charges slow

Tags: iphone

My friends iPhone is charging so slow!

The iPhone charges slow even when it's off. It uses a third party cable and accessories and the 30 pin connector keeps popping out.
**ok.** my friend was placing the iPhone and connecting it to the power outlet, the iPhone *started* charging, but frequently stops charging. I checked the 30 pin connector and it was popping out. Any clues to give meh plz

iPhone 4s, iOS 8.3, *my friends iPhone*

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35270/iphone-4-will-charge-in-wall-but-wont-sync-or-charge-via-usb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's the third-party charger. The official Apple one (the $20 one) is what you need.