# This pop up shows when I use a third party cable

Tags: ipad, lightning

[image: wow I was using a _mfi certified _ lightning cable and this appears. **can anyone help me?** plz!]

This appears when I use a cable that is mfi certified to charge my iPad. Why?

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/35270/iphone-4-will-charge-in-wall-but-wont-sync-or-charge-via-usb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You're using a poor quality cable (or, very unlikely, the port is obstructed.](http://osxdaily.com/2015/02/12/cable-is-not-certified-error-message-iphone-ipad/) [There are many cables that say they are MFi certified that are not: you can check if it is here.](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) You should stop using this cable **immediately** as it could cause [real damage to your iPad.](http://www.payetteforward.com/my-iphone-cable-is-hot-can-a-hot-cable-cause-damage/) While I don't know if this will apply to your cable, [Apple has a take back program for third party adapters](https://www.apple.com/support/usbadapter-takeback/) <s>and may give you some credit towards buying a proper adapter.</s> (*correction*: the cheaper price has been discontinued.)